# Spend $250 & Save $20% Promocode (excluding all sale items)

Tags: price-rules

I am trying to create a promocode for my customers where they can save 20% if they spend over $250, but I would like to exclude the items I have on sale.

I don't have a sales category. My products that are on sale automatically show in the sales page which is setup as a content page and it not a cateogry so I can't use the sales category in the shopping cart rules.

Can someone please give me a hand. When do I use a condition and when do I use an action?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter for `special_price` products.

Go to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes`, search for `special_price` and set `Use for Promo Rule Conditions` to **yes**

Then go the the shopping cart promotions and create a new rule with the following values for `conditions`

[image: Rule Conditions]

By search for a **.** in the `special_price` field you can check if it's empty (it's saved as a decimal). As long as it's empty the product is not on sale and should count for the total of $250.

You can set the rest of the values in the other tabs to your liking